# PHP AUTH на удаленном сайте

Tags: php, auth

Есть система видеокамер, управляются оборудованием trendnet. Чтобы посмотреть изображение с камеры нужно ввести в браузер адрес типа http://192.168.0.100/video/mjpg.cgi, которое запрашивает авторизацию. Мне нужно написать скрипт, который авторизовывается на устройстве управления камерами и показать картинку.

в принцыпе:

```
<img src="http://192.168.0.100/video/mjpg.cgi">
```

должно показать, но php должен авторизоваться, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

почитайте про [cURL](http://xdan.ru/avtorizacija-na-sajte-pri-pomoshhi-curl-php.html), оно куки поддерживает...
успешность зависит от того как на том сайте авторизация реализована...

Answer (score 1):

cURL умеет авторизовываться. Смотрите [опции CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php): `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` и `CURLOPT_USERPWD`. Вытащите так картинку и покажете ее на выходе скрипта. На странице свое напишите соотв. что-то типа

```
<img src="http://192.168.10.10/camera.php?cam=123">
```

Comment: Работает, только вот проблема. Картинка, которая отправляется с адреса http://192.168.0.100/video/mjpg.cgi слишком огромная, то есть по мере загрузки она обновляется и показывает "живую", если открыть прямо в браузере. Если вставить в тэг img то грузится долго (30 секунд - set_time_out) и ничего не показывает.

Comment: На вопрос про PHP авторизацию вы получили исчерпывающий ответ?
А про таймауты и слишком большие картинки открывайте отдельный вопрос.